# Iteration through std containers in openmp

Tags: c++, stl, openmp

I'm trying to use openmp to multithread a loop through std::set. When I write the following code -

```
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (std::set<A>::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i) {
            const A a = *i;
            operate(a);
    }
```

I get this error:

```
error: invalid type for iteration variable 'i'
error: invalid controlling predicate
error: invalid increment expression.
```

**Is there an another, correct way to iterate through std containers using openmp?**
I know I can use `int i` and iterate from `0` to `s.size()` and an iterator or `operator[]` in the loop body, but this looks much less clean.

Comment: Which compiler? GCC has a parallel implementation (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html) of `std::for_each` which should do the trick for you. Maybe you can also look at the source there? See also http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/singler/mcstl/.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Loop parallelization for stl iterators only works since OpenMP 3.0, and only for random access iterators (e.g. `vector` and `deque`). You should be able to do something like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel {
   for (std::set<A>::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i) {
      #pragma omp single nowait {
         operate(*i);
      }
   }
}
```

Overhead is quite big though because each thread iterates over the whole sequence (but only executes `operate` on some of it). Your method using an `int i` is more efficient.

As an alternative take a look at GCC's parallel implementation of [`std::for_each`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html). See my comment.

**EDIT**: The STL [Parallism TS](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P0024R2.html), which will most likely be part of C++17, might be a good option in the future for iterating over standard containers.

Comment: `std::set` does not have the `operator[]` and msvc only supports openmp 2.0 :/

Comment: @quimnuss: the [Parallel STL](https://parallelstl.codeplex.com/) for msvc might be helpful. [Parallelism TS](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P0024R2.html) will most likely be part of C++17, so this should be reasonably future-proof (but might still have bugs and not be feature complete, I haven't followed the MS implementation too closely).

Comment: Can you possibly clarify since when does `for_each` has OpenMP annotations?  E.g., which gcc version was it introduced in?  I'm trying GCC 4.7 (OpenMP 3.1), and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @cnst: I'm working on Windows right now and don't have GCC here, so my answer might be a bit wrong. But from memory (and [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/parallel_mode_using.html)): you have to compile with a couple of flags, e.g. `-O3 -fopenmp -march=native` in addition to your other flags. Now you can either add `-D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL` (=complete `std` parallel), or selectively `#include <parallel/algorithm>` and then use e.g. `__gnu_parallel::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`. If this does not work, let me know and I'll check over the weekend.

Comment: And this remark in [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/parallel_mode_using.html) is important, @cnst: _"Please note that this doesn't necessarily mean that everything will end up being executed in a parallel manner [...]."_ So, if your code does not seem to run in parallel, set up a toy project with a huge vector with random data and and sort it to be sure that everything works as expected. See also the [tuning section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode_design.html#parallel_mode.design.tuning) of the documentation.