# GDB debug output for multi-thread program

Tags: linux, multithreading, gdb

All,

I am debuging a 24-thread program with GDB, now I have find which line in the code the error occurs, but I cannot tell what the error is from the output of GDB. The followsing line of code leads to the error, it's just a normal insertion to a map structure.

```
current_node->children.insert(std::pair<string, ComponentTrieNode*>(comps[j], temp_node));
```

I used GDB to find out in which thread the error happens and switched to that thread, the `backtrace` command shows the function calls in the stack. (The last several lines try to print the value of some variables in a function, but failed.)

What should I do to clear know what error is happening?

```
[root@localhost nameComponentEncoding]# gdb NCE_david
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora (7.2.90.20110429-36.fc15)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /mnt/disk2/experiments_BLOODMOON/two_stage_bloom_filter/programs/nameComponentEncoding/NCE_david...done.
(gdb) r /mnt/disk2/FIB_with_port/10_1.txt /mnt/disk2/trace/a_10_1.trace /mnt/disk2/FIB_with_port/10_2.txt
Starting program: /mnt/disk2/experiments_BLOODMOON/two_stage_bloom_filter/programs/nameComponentEncoding/NCE_david /mnt/disk2/FIB_with_port/10_1.txt /mnt/disk2/trace/a_10_1.trace /mnt/disk2/FIB_with_port/10_2.txt
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x7fffd2bf5700 (LWP 13129)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd23f4700 (LWP 13130)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd1bf3700 (LWP 13131)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd13f2700 (LWP 13132)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd0bf1700 (LWP 13133)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd03f0700 (LWP 13134)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcfbef700 (LWP 13135)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcf3ee700 (LWP 13136)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcebed700 (LWP 13137)]
[New Thread 0x7fffce3ec700 (LWP 13138)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcdbeb700 (LWP 13139)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcd3ea700 (LWP 13140)]
[New Thread 0x7fffccbe9700 (LWP 13141)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcc3e8700 (LWP 13142)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcbbe7700 (LWP 13143)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcb3e6700 (LWP 13144)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcabe5700 (LWP 13145)]
[New Thread 0x7fffca3e4700 (LWP 13146)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc9be3700 (LWP 13147)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc93e2700 (LWP 13148)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc8be1700 (LWP 13149)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc83e0700 (LWP 13150)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc7bdf700 (LWP 13151)]
this is thread 1
this is thread 7
this is thread 14
this is thread 18
this is thread 2
this is thread 19
this is thread 6
this is thread 8
this is thread 24
base: 64312646
this is thread 11
this is thread 5
this is thread 12
this is thread 13
this is thread 3
this is thread 15
this is thread 16
this is thread 17
this is thread 4
this is thread 20
this is thread 21
this is thread 22
this is thread 23
this is thread 9
this is thread 10

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffc8be1700 (LWP 13149)]
std::local_Rb_tree_rotate_left (__x=0xa057c90, __root=@0x608118) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/tree.cc:126
126         __x->_M_right = __y->_M_left;
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame
  24   Thread 0x7fffc7bdf700 (LWP 13151) "NCE_david" compare (__n=<optimized out>, __s2=<optimized out>, __s1=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/bits/char_traits.h:257
  (... other 22 threads not listed)
  2    Thread 0x7fffd2bf5700 (LWP 13129) "NCE_david" compare (__n=<optimized out>, __s2=<optimized out>, __s1=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/bits/char_traits.h:257
  1    Thread 0x7ffff7fe57a0 (LWP 13126) "NCE_david" strtok () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strtok.S:76
(gdb) thread 22
[Switching to thread 22 (Thread 0x7fffc8be1700 (LWP 13149))]
#0  std::local_Rb_tree_rotate_left (__x=0xa057c90, __root=@0x608118) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/tree.cc:126
126         __x->_M_right = __y->_M_left;

(gdb) bt
#0  std::local_Rb_tree_rotate_left (__x=0xa057c90, __root=@0x608118) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/tree.cc:126
#1  0x0000003cdd26e848 in std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance (__insert_left=<optimized out>, __x=0x7fffc0005ba0, __p=<optimized out>, __header=...)
    at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/tree.cc:266
#2  0x00000000004029ca in std::_Rb_tree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, ComponentTrieNode*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, ComponentTrieNode*> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, ComponentTrieNode*> > >::_M_insert_ (this=0x608108, __x=<optimized out>, __p=0x16cd3e30, __v=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_pair.h:87
#3  0x0000000000402b7d in std::_Rb_tree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, ComponentTrieNode*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, ComponentTrieNode*> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, ComponentTrieNode*> > >::_M_insert_unique (this=0x608108, __v=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_tree.h:1281
#4  0x000000000040444c in insert (__x=..., this=0x608108) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.0/../../../../include/c++/4.6.0/bits/stl_map.h:518
#5  ComponentTrie::add_prefix (this=0x7fffffffe2e0, prefix_input=<optimized out>, port=10) at ComponentTrie_david.cpp:112
#6  0x0000000000401c3b in main._omp_fn.0 () at NameComponentEncoding_david.cpp:277
#7  0x0000003cd2607fea in gomp_thread_start (xdata=<optimized out>) at ../../../libgomp/team.c:115
#8  0x0000003cd0607cd1 in start_thread (arg=0x7fffc8be1700) at pthread_create.c:305
#9  0x0000003cd02dfd3d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:115

(gdb) p 'ComponentTrie::add_prefix(char*, int)'::comps[j]
No symbol "comps" in specified context.
(gdb) p 'ComponentTrie::add_prefix(char*, int)'::prefix
No symbol "prefix" in specified context.
```

Edit: I have run the code with `valgrind --tool=memcheck`, the following is the result.

```
[root@localhost nameComponentEncoding]# valgrind --tool=memcheck ./NCE_david /mnt/disk2/FIB_with_port/10_1.txt /mnt/disk2/trace/a_10_1.trace /mnt/disk2/FIB_with_port/10_2.txt
(... many lines omitted)
==13261==
==13261== Thread 11:
==13261== Invalid read of size 1
==13261==    at 0x3CD02849BC: strtok (strtok.S:141)
==13261==    by 0x40426A: ComponentTrie::add_prefix(char*, int) (ComponentTrie_david.cpp:99)
==13261==    by 0x40242C: main._omp_fn.0 (NameComponentEncoding_david.cpp:531)
==13261==    by 0x3CD2607FE9: gomp_thread_start (team.c:115)
==13261==    by 0x3CD0607CD0: start_thread (pthread_create.c:305)
==13261==    by 0x3CD02DFD3C: clone (clone.S:115)
==13261==  Address 0x234422c02 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13261==
==13261== Invalid read of size 1
==13261==    at 0x3CD02849EC: strtok (strtok.S:167)
==13261==    by 0x40426A: ComponentTrie::add_prefix(char*, int) (ComponentTrie_david.cpp:99)
==13261==    by 0x40242C: main._omp_fn.0 (NameComponentEncoding_david.cpp:531)
==13261==    by 0x3CD2607FE9: gomp_thread_start (team.c:115)
==13261==    by 0x3CD0607CD0: start_thread (pthread_create.c:305)
==13261==    by 0x3CD02DFD3C: clone (clone.S:115)
==13261==  Address 0x234422c02 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13261==
Insertion and lookup cost time(us): 994669532   67108864        14.821731       0.067469
component number:4849478, state number: 2545847
Parallel threads:24
==13261==
==13261== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13261==     in use at exit: 4,239,081,584 bytes in 76,746,193 blocks
==13261==   total heap usage: 80,050,114 allocs, 3,303,921 frees, 4,323,622,103 bytes allocated
==13261==
==13261== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13261==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13261==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13261==      possibly lost: 4,111,951,106 bytes in 74,746,429 blocks
==13261==    still reachable: 127,130,478 bytes in 1,999,764 blocks
==13261==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13261== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==13261==
==13261== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13261== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==13261== ERROR SUMMARY: 45 errors from 30 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: @scottt would you please have a look at this problem? Thank you!

Comment: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.` --- that's your error. It means the program tried to access memory that it does not own. This often happens when trying to dereference a NULL pointer.

Comment: @Bloodmoon, there's a class of programming error that would be helpful to rule out first. You're _NOT_ allowing multiple OpenMP threads concurrent access to STL containers like `std::map` without synchronization, right? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513988/iteration-through-std-containers-in-openmp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that the program is segfaulting on this line:

```
current_node->children.insert(std::pair<string, ComponentTrieNode*>(comps[j], temp_node));
```

From the stack trace, we know that the segfault happens deep in the red black tree implementation of `std::map`:

```
#0  std::local_Rb_tree_rotate_left (__x=0xa057c90, __root=@0x608118) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/tree.cc:126
126         __x->_M_right = __y->_M_left;
```

This implies that:

1. The segfault could be caused by:

   1. evaluating `__x->_M_right`
   2. evaluating `__y->_M_left`
   3. storing the right hand side to the left hand side of `__x->_M_right = __y->_M_left`
2. `std::map::insert()` being called implies that the segfault was *NOT* caused while building the arguments to the call. In particular `comps[j]` is not out of bounds.

This leads me to think that your heap was already corrupted by previous memory operation errors by this time and that the crash in `std::map::insert()` is a symptom and not a cause.

Run your program under the Valgrind memcheck tool:

```
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck /mnt/disk2/experiments_BLOODMOON/two_stage_bloom_filter/programs/nameComponentEncoding/NCE_david /mnt/disk2/FIB_with_port/10_1.txt /mnt/disk2/trace/a_10_1.trace /mnt/disk2/FIB_with_port/10_2.txt
```

and carefully read Valgrind's output afterwards to find the first memory error in your program.

Valgrind is implemented as a virtual CPU, so your program would slow down by a factor of ~30. This is time consuming but should allow you to make progress in troubleshooting the problem.

In addition to Valgrind, you might also want to try [enabling debug mode for the `libstdc++` containers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html#debug_mode.using.mode):

> To use the libstdc++ debug mode, compile your application with the compiler flag -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG. Note that this flag changes the sizes and behavior of standard class templates such as std::vector, and therefore you can only link code compiled with debug mode and code compiled without debug mode if no instantiation of a container is passed between the two translation units.

If your program uses no external libraries then rebuilding the whole thing with **-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG** added to **CXXFLAGS** in the `Makefile` should work. Otherwise you'd need to know whether C++ containers are passed between components compiled with and without the debug flag.

### Valgrind Log Review

I'm surprised that you're using `strtok()` in a multi-threaded program. Is **ComponentTrie::add_prefix()** never called from two threads concurrently? While fixing the invalid read by inspecting how `strtok()` is used on **ComponentTrie_david.cpp:99**, you might want to replace `strtok()` with **[strtok_r()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r)** as well.

### Concurrent Access to STL Containers

The standard C++ containers are [explicitly documented](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_concurrency.html) to not do thread synchronization:

> The user code must guard against concurrent function calls which access any particular library object's state when one or more of those accesses modifies the state. An object will be modified by invoking a non-const member function on it or passing it as a non-const argument to a library function. An object will not be modified by invoking a const member function on it or passing it to a function as a pointer- or reference-to-const. Typically, the application programmer may infer what object locks must be held based on the objects referenced in a function call and whether the objects are accessed as const or non-const.

(That's from the GNU `libstdc++` documentation but the C++11 standard essentially specifies the same behavior) Concurrent modifications of `std::map` and other containers is a serious error and likely the culprit that caused the crash. **Guard each container with their own `pthread_mutex_t` or use the OpenMP synchronization mechanisms.**

Comment: Thank you for so detailed analysis, I have run the code with 'valgrind --tool=memcheck' (see edit of the question), and it seems that the only potential error happens at function `strtok`. I will try again with **-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG**.

Comment: @Bloodmoon, I've amended my answer with a Valgrind Log Review part at the end.  By the way, did you see my comment on your question?

Comment: yes, I have seen the comment. 1. For your **Valgrind Log Review** in the answer: **ComponentTrie::add_prefix()** will be called by all the 24 threads, and therefore the `strtok`. You reminded me that this functin may not be thread-safe. I will try `strtok_r()`2. For your comment: I am also suspecting that `std:map` in the stl does support multi-thread, especially I'm invoking the `insert` method.

Comment: @Bloodmoon, I've amended my answer re: concurrent access to `std::map`. A lot of my friends from academic instead of industrial backgrounds write multi-threaded code without thinking about concurrent access to shared data as well and then have a very difficult time adding correct locking retrospectively ... May I suggest that you got lucky that this problem was pointed out explicitly? ;)

Comment: The `strtok` and `std::map::insert` functions are the only two potentials that could lead to the error, I have tried commenting out the `insert` function calls in all the threads, or just call the `insert` by a single thread, everything worked fine. In fact, this program is only a small part in my experiments, I have finished all the other experiments by OpenMP without using any STL containters, thoses programs all work peroperly. And at last I got stuck here at `map`.

Comment: @Bloodmoon, that's very good news. That means after guarding each `std::map` with a mutex the crash would likely be fixed. Using data  structures where you have total control of the details instead of STL containers in the parallel computation part of your program is certainly wise both for performance and correctness.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :)  without your deep analysis I cannot arrive at here by my own! And, to my surprise, this program works fine on Windows! Concurrent calls to `std::map::insert` and `strtok` from multiple threads, they all work properly! I will update the results of the program after revision on Linux. It's deep night here. Thank you again!

Comment: I have fixed the `strtok()` problem and added a mutex to the `std::map` object, now the program can work. Thank you again!