# Selectively enable an OpenMP for loop within a parallel region

Tags: c++, openmp

Is it possible to selectively enable an openmp directive with template parameter or run time variable?

```
this (all threads work on the same for loop).
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { /*...*/ }
}
versus this (each thread works on its own for loop)
#pragma omp parallel
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { /*...*/ }
}
```

---

Update (Testing if clause)

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    bool var = true;
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        #pragma omp for if (var)
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            std::cout << omp_get_thread_num() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Error message (g++ 6, compiled with g++ test.cpp -fopenmp)

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8:25: error: ‘if’ is not valid for ‘#pragma omp for’
         #pragma omp for if (var)
                         ^~
```

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel if(variable)`

Comment: Both versions are parallel, mostly I want to selectively enable the `#pragma omp for line`. I will try to look up if the if clause can work with the for clause. thanks.

Comment: it does. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5187hzke.aspx hopefully this is true for all compilers.

Comment: tried g++ 6. `if’ is not valid for ‘#pragma omp for’`

Comment: I can't help but wonder in what kind of code you would want to conditionally execute each loop iteration either 4 times or 4 * nthread times. This sounds very much like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/317725)

Comment: @Zulan Implemented different data structures (sparse and dense array etc. some saves more memory than others.). The data structure can be divided into two kinds. The two kinds need two different ways to loop over them. And then there is a class template that implements algorithms that works on all of the data structures. I don't want to implement the loops for each kind of data structure or repeat lots of code.

Comment: @Zulan guess you are right. That thing is just too ugly to use. Probably I will try to find another way to duplicate less code.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of a work around. Don't know if it is possible to get rid of conditionals for getting the thread id.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    constexpr bool var = true;
    int n_threads = omp_get_num_procs();
    std::cout << "n_threads: " << n_threads << "\n";
    std::vector<std::stringstream> s(omp_get_num_procs());

    #pragma omp parallel if (var) 
    {

        const int thread_id0 = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            int thread_id1;
            if (var) {
                thread_id1 = thread_id0;
            } else {
                thread_id1 = omp_get_thread_num();
            }

            #pragma omp for
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
                s[thread_id1] << i << ", ";
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "thread " << i << ": " 
                  << s[i].str() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output (when `var == true`):

```
n_threads: 8
thread 0: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
thread 1: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
thread 2: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
thread 3: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
thread 4: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
thread 5: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
thread 6: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
thread 7: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
```

Output (when `var == false`):

```
n_threads: 8
thread 0: 0, 
thread 1: 1, 
thread 2: 2, 
thread 3: 3, 
thread 4: 4, 
thread 5: 5, 
thread 6: 6, 
thread 7: 7,
```

Comment: this works for both clang and g++. not sure about intel compiler.

Comment: It won't work as expected if nested parallelism is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idiomatic C++ solution is to hide the different OpenMP pragmas behind algorithmic overloads.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

#include <type_traits>
template <bool ALL_PARALLEL>
struct impl;

template<>
struct impl<true>
{
  template<typename ITER, typename CALLABLE>
  void operator()(ITER begin, ITER end, const CALLABLE& func) {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
      for (ITER i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
        func(i);
      }
    }
  }
};

template<>
struct impl<false>
{
  template<typename ITER, typename CALLABLE>
  void operator()(ITER begin, ITER end, const CALLABLE& func) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (ITER i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
      func(i);
    }
  }
};

// This is just so we don't have to write parallel_foreach()(...)
template <bool ALL_PARALLEL, typename ITER, typename CALLABLE>
void parallel_foreach(ITER begin, ITER end, const CALLABLE& func)
{
    impl<ALL_PARALLEL>()(begin, end, func);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr bool var = false;
    int n_threads = omp_get_num_procs();
    std::cout << "n_threads: " << n_threads << "\n";
    std::vector<std::stringstream> s(omp_get_num_procs());

    parallel_foreach<var>(0, 8, [&s](auto i) {
        s[omp_get_thread_num()] << i << ", ";
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "thread " << i << ": " 
                  << s[i].str() << "\n";
    }
}
```

If you use some specific types, you can do an overload by type instead of to using the `bool` template parameter and iterate through elements rather than the numerical indexed loop. Note that you can use C++ random access iterators in OpenMP worksharing loops! Depending on your types you might very well be able to implement an iterator that hides everything about the internal data access form the caller.

Comment: I thought overhead was quite big for iterator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513988/iteration-through-std-containers-in-openmp Not sure if that is still true now. After reading that, I avoid writing iterator for classes if it is for openmp for loop.

Comment: You misread the linked answer. The example he gives is for `std::set`, which has no random access iterator. Hence he does not use the a loop worksharing construct (`#pragma omp (parallel) for`), but a hand-made loop. If you use a normal `#pragma omp for` on a random access iterator, there is no inherent overhead. Your optimization mileage may vary, so do measure and compare.

Comment: thanks. guess I will add random access iterators in the next project ...

Comment: another way is to make a macro function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    constexpr bool var = false;
    int n_threads = omp_get_num_procs();
    std::cout << "n_threads: " << n_threads << "\n";
    std::vector<std::stringstream> s(omp_get_num_procs());

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        const int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
        if (var) {
            #pragma omp for
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
                s[thread_id] << i << ", ";
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
                s[thread_id] << i << ", ";
            } // code duplication
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "thread " << i << ": " 
                  << s[i].str() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You realise that the code in the `else` block actually creates a nested parallel region, which might lead to a surprising result? The only reason it might seem to work as the OP wants is that nested parallelism is disabled by default and the region will execute in serial in each thread.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that by removing `#pragma omp parallel for` in the `else` block.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that you are the OP. You should really combine both your answers into one.